# How can I make a list of elements Selenium?

Tags: python, list, loops, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver with Python , I need to make this in a loop:
I can do something like this:

```
a=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr/td[1]")
b=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr/td[2]")
c=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr/td[3]")
d=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr/td[n]")
```

1) But I want something like this:

```
var==browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr/td[ALL_value]")
```

2) I need output as array like this:

```
 output=[ANDERSON,ISAIAH,DWIGHT,....]
```

Here's the code for that :

```
    import xlwt
    from tempfile import TemporaryFile
    from selenium import webdriver
    browser =webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get( "https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s" )
    element=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr/td[1]" )#I want this as list
    output=element.text #I want this as list
    print output

    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')
    output=[ANDERSON,ISAIAH,DWIGHT,....]
    output= [a,b,c]
    for row, array in enumerate(output):
          for col, value in enumerate(array):
             sheet1.write(row, col, value)
    name = "this.xls"
    book.save(name)
    book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

Can anyone help me?
 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_elements_by_xpath()` in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and don't specify the cell index:

```
[td.text for td in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr/td")]
```

If you want to have a *list of cell values per row*, you would need to produce a list of lists:

```
[[td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
 for row in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr")]
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get("https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s")
>>> data = [[td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")] for row in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='mrc_main_table']/tr")]
>>> pprint(data)
[['ACTON', 'CLINTON', 'WAYNE', 'M', 'W', '35', 'STURGEON', 'MO'],
 ['ALLEN', 'SHAUN', 'PHILLIP', 'M', 'W', '28', 'COLUMBIA', 'MO'],
 ['ANDERSON', 'ISAIAH', 'DWIGHT', 'M', 'B', '19', 'COLUMBIA', 'MO'],
 ...
 ['DONATI', 'ROBERT', 'KEITH', 'M', 'W', '52', 'COLUMBIA', 'MO'],
 ['DONIGIAN', 'CHARLES', 'ROSS', 'M', 'W', '20', 'COLUMBIA', 'MO']]
```

Comment: Good job ... Thank you so much